# Passing vector of derived, templated class

Tags: c++, templates, vector

I'd like to define a general function `foo` that takes data, perhaps manipulates underlying class variables, and returns an `int`. However, when I attempt to create a separate function that takes a vector of `foo` objects, the compiler fails to deduce the template parameter. The following illustrates what I've tried:

```
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
class Base {
public:
  virtual int foo(const T& x) const = 0;
};

template <typename T>
class Derived : public Base<std::vector<T> > { // specialize for vector data
public:
  virtual int foo(const std::vector<T>& x) const { return 0;}
};

template <typename T>
int bar(const T& x, const std::vector< Base<T> >& y) {
  if(y.size() > 0)
    return y[0].foo(x);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  std::vector<double> x;
  std::vector< Derived<double> > y;
  bar(x, y);
}
```

This fails to find a matching function for `bar`, with the notes:

```
main.cc:16:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cc:24:11: note:   mismatched types ‘Base<T>’ and ‘Derived<double>’
```

and

```
main.cc:24:11: note:   ‘std::vector<Derived<double> >’ is not derived \
from ‘const std::vector<Base<T> >’
```

Forgive me if the answer lies in an already-posted thread; I've read quite a number that do seem related, but don't, to my knowledge, address this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First note that `std::vector<Base<T> >` and `std::vector<Derived<T> >` are different types, even if `Base<std::vector<T>>` is the base of `Derived<T>`. Type conversion doesn't happen in template type deduction. So `T` cannot be deduced by matching the second argument `y` of type `std::vector<Derived<double>>` that you pass to `bar` with `std::vector<Base<T>>`.

Next, suppose we make `y` of the "right" type

```
std::vector< Base<double> > y;
```

so you can pass it to `bar`. Now in principle we can deduce `T` by matching the second parameter in `bar` of type `std::vector<Base<T>>` with the type `std::vector< Base<double> >` of `y`. So `T` is deduced as `double`, however don't forget that `x`, which you pass as the first parameter to `bar`, has type `vector<double>`, so from `x` we will deduce `T` as `vector<double>`, which of course is inconsistent with `double` deduced from `y`. So type deduction fails.

[Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ea5676de64b516eb) is a simplified example that replicates your issue.

Comment: Sure, but in my case `x` and `y` are consistent. The compiler would catch something like what you've posted, no?

Comment: Right, but the issue in my code doesn't seem to be one of inconsistent template parameters, but of some inability to recognize that `Derived<double>` is a `Base< std::vector<double> >`. I agree that the code is susceptible to the sort of mistakes you've highlighted.

Comment: I guess I'd just like a little more detail into why `T` cannot be deduced.

Comment: The problem *is* the fact that you try to match `vector<Derived<double>>` with `vector<Base<T>>`, which are **totally unrelated** for the compiler, even if `Derived` and `Base` are related. Ignore the `x` for the moment, just focus on the second parameter. See the example I posted [live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ea5676de64b516eb).

Comment: I think I'm on the same page now. Is there any way of notifying the compiler of the relationship between the two classes? Or in general a way to fix it without specifying that `bar` takes a `vector<Derived<T> >`? Many thanks for your persistent help!

Comment: @glinka Not as I know of, as long as you keep the parameter `std::vector< Base<T> >`. Probably you can change your design, so you don't need the additional `vector` that surrounds `Base<T>`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79461/discussion-between-glinka-and-vsoftco).